# jQuery smoothscroll with callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone of you know any jQuery plugin (or js script) that enables scrolling through page smoothly, and enables to use callbacks, or to call certain function, when scrolling is completed?

Thanks.

Comment: what you call scrolling complete ?

Comment: whatever, let's say `alert('scrolling done!');`

Comment: I mean when physically you want to say "scrolling done" after short timeout when scroll wasn't done ?

Comment: Right after scrolling is done.

Comment: **when** scrolling should be considered done?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) will scroll smoothly through a page, and offers an onAfter function that allows you to specify a callback.

Comment: thanks, but scrollTo plugin doesn't cover mouse scrolling and draggin scroll bars...

Comment: @LorDex - you didn't specify that _users_ were doing the scrolling in the wording of your question.  I think this is a fine answer for one interpretation of what you asked, since it could be understood that you wanted something to automatically scroll the screen.  +1 to barry.